# VBScript DateDiff month

Tags: vbscript, datediff

I am having a problem about getting the month datedifference between two dates.
Here is a sample:

```
DateDiff("m","2014-10-17","2014-10-30")
```

The above code returns 0 months since it is less than a month. But,

```
DateDiff("m","2014-10-17","2014-11-01")
```

returns 1 which should not be since it is still 15 days.

My problem is I want to see if these two dates already exceed a month but it seems that it calculates 1 month only when the month part of the date is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateDiff` calculates the span between two timestamps with the precision defined in the first parameter. From what you described in your question and comments you rather seem to be looking for something like this:

```
ds1 = "2014-10-17"
ds2 = "2014-10-30"

d1 = CDate(ds1)
d2 = CDate(ds2)

diff = DateDiff("m", d1, d2)
If diff > 0 And Day(d2) < Day(d1) Then diff = diff - 1

WScript.Echo diff & " full months have passed between " & ds1 & " and " & ds2 & "."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate day difference between two dates using 'DateDiff("d",date1,date2)'.
Then calculate number of full-month by dividing 30 days.

Following is an example.

```
monthDiff = int(DateDiff("d","2014-10-17","2014-11-01") / 30)
```

As you know, days of months differs by month. For example, November has 30 days and December has 31 days.

If you wish to use 30 days a month when first day is on November, and to use 31 days a month whe first day is on December, the code need a table of days of months and routine to handle month information.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to avoid. These built in functions are supposed to make it easier but it seems like they are not ideal. And then there's the problem with leap years too. Hope someone can give a source code to do this.

Comment: 'DateDiff' does not have your IDEAL function. There are two way to solve your problem, 1) ask to developpers of VBScript for improving 'DataDiff' as you want, 2) find a way to roundabout insufficient function of 'DataDiff'.  StackOverflow is not a developper of VBScript, so you should not ask for solution of 1) way.  Good Luck!

Comment: @kenjohnny09 If you didnt want this as an answer it would have been a good idea to mention it. You should combine both. If the the month difference is one then check the days to be sure. In your example 11-10 equals one which is most likely the core of the answer. As an extra check you could compare days in the month to get your math exact.

Comment: @Fumu7 yes, you have a point. I was hoping for a quick fix about this but i guess there's a lot more to it. I'll go with your number 2.