# Monthly generation with a given dates

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, datediff

**Trying to Achieve**

I fixed a date on my code say 31-01-2019. Then everyday I will execute my code but only on 28-02-2019/29-02-2020, 31-03-2019, 30-04-2019... I wish to execute the code. It is something like monthly generation. In addition, if the fixed date is 30-01-2019, I wish to execute the code on 28-02-2019/29-02-2020, 30-03-2019, 30-04-2019...

**For example**

**What I have done**

I have followed the question [VBScript DateDiff month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030073/vbscript-datediff-month), and have tried out the following code but it is not working.

**If I were to have a date say 31-Jan-2010 by DateAdd**

```
endFeb = DateAdd("m",1,"31-Jan-10")
endMar = DateAdd("m",1,endFeb)
endApr = DateAdd("m",1,endMar)
```

**The result**

```
endFeb: 28/02/2010
endMar: 28/03/2010
endApr: 28/04/2010
```

**What I want is**

```
endFeb: 28/02/2010
endMar: 31/03/2010
endApr: 30/04/2010
```

**Code**

```
sFixedDate = "2019-01-31" '==== Fixed
sProcessDate = "2019-02-28"  '==== Changes daily

d1 = CDate(sFixedDate)
d2 = CDate(sProcessDate)

diff = DateDiff("m", d1, d2)

If request("btnProcess") <> "" Then
    If diff Mod 1 = 0 Then  '=== Not as simple as I thought
        '=== Trying to do monthly GENERATION. 
        '===Excecute the CODE
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you want to run something on the last day of each month. Meaning that the day after would be a different month, so you could do something like this for calculating the last day of the next month:

```
today    = Date
tomorrow = today + 1
If request("btnProcess") <> "" Then
    If Month(today) <> Month(tomorrow) Then
        endNextMonth = DateAdd("m", 1, tomorrow) - 1
    End If
End If
```

To get the last day for any given month adjust the number of months to add to tomorrow's date.

The above assumes that you're doing the calculation on the last day of a month. If you want to calculate the last day of any given month on any day of a month please see [Ekkehard Horner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54195348/1630171).

Comment: No... I have a date say 15th of Jan 2019 (Can be any dates). I want to execute the code when it is 15th of Feb, 15th of March, 15th of Apr and so on.... In addition when I have a date on say 31st of Jan 2019. I want to execute the code when it is 28th Feb 2019/29th Feb 2019 , when it is 31th March, when it is 30th Apr. How do I check if it already 1 month, 2 month, 3 month ...

Comment: See if I do the following 
`endFeb = DateAdd("m",1,"31-Jan-10")
        endMar = DateAdd("m",1,endFeb)
        endApr = DateAdd("m",1,endMar)`
I will get   
endFeb: 28/02/2010
endMar: 28/03/2010
endApr: 28/04/2010
Instead of 
**endFeb: 28/02/2010**
**endMar: 31/03/2010**
**endApr: 30/04/2010**

Answer (score 1):

Use DateSerial:

```
For m = 1 To 13
     d1 = DateSerial(2019, m, 1) ' First day of month is easy
     d2 = DateAdd("d", d1, -1)   ' Last day of previous month is just 1 day before
     WScript.Echo m, d1, d2
Next

cscript lom.vbs
1 01.01.2019 31.12.2018
2 01.02.2019 31.01.2019
3 01.03.2019 28.02.2019
4 01.04.2019 31.03.2019
5 01.05.2019 30.04.2019
6 01.06.2019 31.05.2019
7 01.07.2019 30.06.2019
8 01.08.2019 31.07.2019
9 01.09.2019 31.08.2019
10 01.10.2019 30.09.2019
11 01.11.2019 31.10.2019
12 01.12.2019 30.11.2019
13 01.01.2020 31.12.2019
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like for a given start date, you want to calculate x months into the future what that new date is, and if the start date as a day that is greater than the future month, to give the last day of the month instead.

```
    Function CalculateFutureDate(startDate, monthsInFuture)
        ' Assumes startDate is in the past
        Dim dtRepeatDate
        Dim dtNewDate
        If (IsDate(startDate)) Then
            dtRepeatDate = CDate(startDate)
            ' months between now and Start Date
            Dim intMonthsToAdd
            Dim dtCurrentDate
            dtCurrentDate = Now()
            intMonthsToAdd = DateDiff("m", startDate, dtCurrentDate)
            If intMonthsToAdd > 0 And Day(startDate) < Day(dtCurrentDate) Then
                intMonthsToAdd = intMonthsToAdd - 1
            End If
            ' Add the future months to the month offset
            intMonthsToAdd = intMonthsToAdd + monthsInFuture
            ' Now calculate future date
            dtNewDate = DateAdd("m", intMonthsToAdd, dtRepeatDate)
            CalculateFutureDate = dtNewDate
        End If
    End Function
```

And then you can do something like:

```
CalculateFutureDate(CDate("2019-01-31"), intFutureMonths)
```

This will output:

```
?CalculateFutureDate(CDate("2019-01-31"), 1)
2/28/2019
?CalculateFutureDate(CDate("2019-01-31"), 2)
3/31/2019
?CalculateFutureDate(CDate("2019-01-31"), 3)
4/30/2019
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    dtLoan = CDate("2019-01-30")
    dtProcess = CDate ("2020-02-28")

    'dtLoan = CDate("2019-01-31")
    'dtProcess = CDate ("2020-02-29")

    'dtLoan = CDate("2019-02-28")
    'dtProcess = CDate ("2020-02-29")


    if LastDateOfMonth(dtLoan) = dtLoan AND dtProcess = LastDateOfMonth(dtProcess) then

        response.write " this mean that the Loan date is end of the month, say 31 Jan, 28, 29 of Feb, 31 Feb "
        response.write " and Process Date is also end of the month " & "<br>" 

        response.write " **** End of the month Loan Date : " & dtLoan & "<br>"
        response.write " **** End of the month Process Date : " & dtProcess & "<br>"

    elseif LastDateOfMonth(dtLoan) <> dtLoan AND dtProcess <> LastDateOfMonth(dtProcess) then

        daysFromEndOfLoanMth = DateDiff("d",LastDateOfMonth(dtLoan),dtLoan)
        response.write " How many days from end of Loan month: " & daysFromEndOfLoanMth & "<br>"

        daysFromEndOfProcessMth = DateAdd("d",daysFromEndOfLoanMth,LastDateOfMonth(dtProcess))
        response.write " From end of the month Add " & daysFromEndOfLoanMth & " Days = " & daysFromEndOfProcessMth & "<br>"
        response.write " The date of process : " & dtProcess & "<br>"

        dtShouldProcess = day(dtLoan) & "/" & Month(dtProcess) & "/" & Year(dtProcess)

        if isDate(dtShouldProcess) then
            dtShouldProcess=CDate(dtShouldProcess)
        else
            dtShouldProcess=daysFromEndOfProcessMth
        end if

        response.write " ** The date of should Process : ** " & dtShouldProcess & "<br>"
        if dtProcess = dtShouldProcess then
        'if dtProcess = daysFromEndOfProcessMth then

            response.write " **** Loan Date : " & dtLoan & "<br>"
            response.write " **** Process Date : " & dtProcess & "<br>"

        end if

    'daysFromEndOfProcessMth =  DateDiff("d",LastDateOfMonth(dtProcess1),dtProcess1)
    'response.write " How many days from Process Date end of the month: " & daysFromEndOfProcessMth & "<br>"

    end if
```